# bootstrap mobile collapsing order (right to left) without pull-push

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row with 2 elements and I'm trying to have the second element come on top when it gets collapsed to mobile.

I am able to easily do it with push-pull, but the problem is that I don't have control of how the html is rendered. 
The order of my html is below:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color: green">
        here is some text
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: red">
        an image
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am trying to achive this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8" style="background-color: red">
        an image
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4" style="background-color: green">
        here is some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do it with bootstrap classes or any css styling? I only want it to apply on mobile tho.

I really appreciate any help or direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this with help of CSS property of flex. You can order the child elements in mobile. You can learn Flexbox from [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). The working example is in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3mu4rcy3/)

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .inner-rows{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .red {
     order: -1; 
  }
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 inner-rows green" style="background-color: green">
        here is some text
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 inner-rows red" style="background-color: red">
        an image
    </div>
</div>
```